# How can I get rid of new lines between items in a list?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, information-extraction, part-of-speech

I'm having trouble carrying out named entity recognition using the natural language toolkit. Before I can carry  out NER I have to carry out sentence segmentation, tokenisation and POS tagging. I've done so with the following code:

```
def prepfunc(doc):
    segsents = nltk.sent_tokenize(doc)
    toksents = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in segsents]
    possents = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in toksents]
    return possents

prepfunc(doc)
```

I need the output of this to be on one line:

```
[[('word1', 'tag'), ('word2', 'tag'), ('word3', 'tag'), ...]...]
```

Instead, what I'm getting is each word on a new line:

```
[[('word1', 'tag'),
('word2', 'tag'),
('word3',
'tag'),
...]
...]
```

There is probably some simple principle I'm overlooking, but I can't figure out how to remove the new lines between the list items.

I've looked for a solution to this problem, however, most solutions I've found have been for removing the new lines from a string within a list. I need to remove newlines from the list itself.

Edit:

The code that prints the output is:

```
prepfunc(doclist[0])
```

I've opened the file like so:

```
f='myfile.txt'
opf=open(f, encoding="UTF-8")
doclist=opf.read().split('\n')
```

I'm required to open the file this way.

Comment: Can you show your code that actually prints the output?

Comment: That's really something your trying to do you can't remove new line from a list because there isn't a new line if its the representation `repr` of the list that can be multiline , if you need a single line representation you can use `.join` with the items in the list.

Comment: Hi @ronrothmanℝℝ I've edited the question to include the code that prints the output.

Comment: this is a console issue - the function does not actually print the output. The function returns a list, and then the console helpfully prints it in whatever its default visualization is. If you want it printed a particular way, write a function to print it that way.

Comment: and just in case it isn't clear - there are no newlines _in_ your list. that's just the way it's printed. not sure what you are doing with it, but it looks fine.